# QGIS 3.22.13 - 'Connect Points' plugin error 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'messageBar'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

Trying to use the Connect Points plugin. I can install it no problem, but when I click Plugins > Connect Points > Settings, I get the error. I have tried re-installing the plugin, uninstalling and installing again. Have also searched for some kind of plugin cache I can clear, but no joy. The stack trace is below, is anyone able to help please?

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'messageBar'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/rdeacon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_points\qgis_connect_points.py", line 96, in showSettings
> dlg = Dialog(
> File "C:\Users/rdeacon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_points\dialog.py", line 164, in **init**
> self.fillControls(
> File "C:\Users/rdeacon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_points\dialog.py", line 190, in fillControls
> layerFrom = self.getQGISLayer(curPointsLayerFrom)
> File "C:\Users/rdeacon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_points\dialog.py", line 235, in getQGISLayer
> QgisPlugin(iface=self.parent).showMessageForUser(
> File "C:\Users/rdeacon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\connect_points\qgis_plugin.py", line 82, in showMessageForUser
> self._iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'messageBar'

Answer (score 3):

I guess you found a bug. For a temporary solution, you can try the follows:

1. Go to the plugin folder (Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder, and navigate to `python` > `plugins` > `connect_points`)
2. Open `qgis_connect_points.py`. Add a new argument, as in the image (Line 103-104):

   ```
   103    self._iface.mainWindow(), self._iface
   ```

   [image]
3. Open `dialog.py`. Add `iface=None` and `self._iface = iface` to `__init__`  as in the image:

   ```
   56  parent=None, iface=None

   59  self._iface = iface
   ```

   [image]
4. Change `self.parent` to `self._iface` around Line ~235-240

   [image]
5. Restart QGIS.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now 

'Couldn't load plugin 'connect_points' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method //

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation'

Followed by some file references, then the same TabError again. 

Note - I don't have a code editor with numbered lines, and don't have permissions to install software on my computer, so it's possible I made the edits in the wrong places, as I was doing my best with windows notepad. Are you able to provide a little more context with your screenshots so I can make sure I 've edited correctly please?

Comment: Check indentation. It should be as in the image.